# Python to Java translation

Tags: java, python

i get quite short code of algorithm in python, but i need to translate it to Java. I didnt find any program to do that, so i will really appreciate to help translating it.

I learned python a very little to know the idea how algorithm work.

The biggest problem is because in python all is object and some things are made really very confuzing like

```
sum(self.flow[(source, vertex)] for vertex, capacity in self.get_edges(source))
```

and "self.adj" is like hashmap with multiple values which i have no idea how to put all together. Is any better collection for this code in java?

code is:

```
class FlowNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.adj, self.flow, = {},{}

    def add_vertex(self, vertex):
        self.adj[vertex] = []

    def get_edges(self, v):
        return self.adj[v]

    def add_edge(self, u,v,w=0):
        self.adj[u].append((v,w))
        self.adj[v].append((u,0))
        self.flow[(u,v)] = self.flow[(v,u)] = 0

    def find_path(self, source, sink, path):
        if source == sink:
            return path
        for vertex, capacity in self.get_edges(source):
            residual = capacity - self.flow[(source,vertex)]
            edge = (source,vertex,residual)
            if residual > 0 and not edge in path:
                result = self.find_path(vertex, sink, path + [edge])
                if result != None:
                    return result

    def max_flow(self, source, sink):
        path = self.find_path(source, sink, [])
        while path != None:
            flow = min(r for u,v,r in path)
            for u,v,_ in path:
                self.flow[(u,v)] += flow
                self.flow[(v,u)] -= flow
                path = self.find_path(source, sink, [])
        return sum(self.flow[(source, vertex)] for vertex, capacity in self.get_edges(source))
g = FlowNetwork()
map(g.add_vertex, ['s','o','p','q','r','t'])
g.add_edge('s','o',3)
g.add_edge('s','p',3)
g.add_edge('o','p',2)
g.add_edge('o','q',3)
g.add_edge('p','r',2)
g.add_edge('r','t',3)
g.add_edge('q','r',4)
g.add_edge('q','t',2)
print g.max_flow('s','t')
```

result of this example is "5".

algorithm find max flow in graph(linked list or whatever) from source vertex "s" to destination "t".

Many thanks for any idea

Comment: There is always jython (http://www.jython.org) to create a .class file.
(and if really necessary http://www.google.com/search?q=java+decompiler to decompile the .class into .java files.)

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have anything like Python's comprehension syntax. You'll have to replace it with code that loops over the list and aggregates the value of `sum` as it goes.

Also, `self.flow` looks like a dictionary indexed by pairs. The only way to match this, AFAIK, is to create a class with two fields that implements `hashCode` and `equals` to use as a key for a HashMap.

Comment: [ Michael Aaron Safyan]:yes it is homework, but not python translation. It was about max flow problem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem

Only reason I want this algorithm was because it is really short. But after long night i learn python a bit and translate it by hand. But after that I realize that it has to much overhead so it isnt very useful for bigger graphs.

Now i actually looking for better implementation, so if any one know more of this problem i will appreciate any extra idea. 

Thank you any way.